# Disabling Notification Center pull-down (or re-enabling Safari swipe action)

Tags: ios, notifications

This is a bit of a nit-picky thing, but it's annoyed me ever since I upgraded to iOS 5.  I use my iPhone quite a bit for web surfing, and would often use the swipe action to return back to the top (and address bar) of a long web page.  However, now I'm constantly pulling down the notification center pull-down when all I want to do is return to the top of the page.  Is there any way to disable or change the swipe-to-pull-down notification center?  At least in Safari?  Or is it gone for good now....

Comment: That pulldown is extremely annoying for all sorts of reasons.  I really wish one could disable it permanently.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To return to the top of a long web page, just tap the Status Bar (at the top that also display the current time and battery status) instead of swiping. It works in many other apps too.